# How do I get my script to fit properly in mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

Problem: I'm using the [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/slate) slate theme & it's fits perfectly on my mobile device but my slot machine will not fit to the point where it overlaps the whole template

My [website](http://megacoincasino.com/slots)

I've tried using this but no luck..

`<head>`
   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
`</head>`

Below is my slots.css

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 662px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.wrapper-old{
    background: #c3d825; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c3d825 1%, #e6f0a3 30%, #e9efba 50%, #e6f0a3 70%, #c3d825 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(1%,#c3d825), color-stop(30%,#e6f0a3), color-stop(50%,#e9efba), color-stop(70%,#e6f0a3), color-stop(100%,#c3d825)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #c3d825 1%,#e6f0a3 30%,#e9efba 50%,#e6f0a3 70%,#c3d825 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c3d825 1%,#e6f0a3 30%,#e9efba 50%,#e6f0a3 70%,#c3d825 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c3d825 1%,#e6f0a3 30%,#e9efba 50%,#e6f0a3 70%,#c3d825 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c3d825 1%,#e6f0a3 30%,#e9efba 50%,#e6f0a3 70%,#c3d825 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c3d825', endColorstr='#c3d825',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.slot {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 140px;
    font-size: 140px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    border-left: 0px solid #999;
}
.slot:first-child{
    border-left: 0px;
}
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.slot > li {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #D10707;
    font-family: 'Gravitas One', serif;
    text-shadow: -3px -3px 3px #000, 3px -3px 3px #000, -3px 3px 3px #000, 3px 3px 3px #000;
}


.slot-icon {
    background: url('/assets/img/icons-sprite.jpg') no-repeat;
    height: 140px;
    width: 130px;
    position: relative;
}
    .slot-icon-bell {
        background-position: -145px -125px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-cherry {
        background-position: -145px -301px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-watch {
        background-position: -145px -479px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-drink {
        background-position: -325px -125px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-melon {
        background-position: -325px -301px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-woman {
        background-position: -325px -479px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-altcoin {
        background-position: -532px -125px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-lemon {
        background-position: -542px -301px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-ring {
        background-position: -545px -479px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-gloves {
        background-position: -721px -125px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-wild1 {
        background-position: -721px -301px !important;
    }
    .slot-icon-wild2 {
        background-position: -721px -479px !important;
    }

.game {
    background: black;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 712px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding: 0 25px 10px;
    color: white;
}

.gameRow {
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.gameData {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 29px;
}

.odds {
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn-spin {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.sm-margin {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.payout-icon{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
}

.row {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bootply demo of your code;
http://www.bootply.com/nzMJTgR7lR

I have replaced the fixed widths for the game and wrapper CSS classes with max-width.

You will need to make the images responsive `class="img-responsive"` to resize to smaller screens. You might need to read some of the Bootstrap documentation;
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

However I'm not sure that your background image sprite will work as responsive.

Answer (score 0):

your game css code :

```
.game {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding: 0 25px 10px;
    width: 712px;
}
```

you should user diferent width depending on screen resolution for .game class

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  body {
    width: 650px;
  }
}
```

Comment: So like this?  @media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  body {
    width: 650px;
  }
}
.game {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding: 0 25px 10px;
    width: 712px;
}

Comment: right You can add any css you need just respect max-width:  and min-width: media querys

Comment: it looks good on the ipad 3 but I still can't get it to format correctly for the iphone 5c?

Comment: @media all and (max-width: 480x) and (min-width: 320px) {
  body {
    width: 480px;
  }
}

Comment: iphone 5c has 1136 x 640 pixels screen resolution so you should use different @media queries for each device. Because each device has different sceen resolution. Also you should check your css for fixed width for other html elements.